# Automatically creating new rows based on a value

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a number of rows in a table based on the value of record in a different table.

i.e Table A has two columns NumberID, Number and TableB has MonthID, Month, Amount

When TableA.Number gets a value of say 5 I want TableB to be updated with 5 new rows. The values of TableB.Month and TableB.Amount will then be entered manually. Can this be done?

Comment: If the values will be entered manually, why not create the rows manually?

Comment: I need to be able to restrict the number of rows available as it feeds to a web application.

Comment: So, why can you restrict it when TableA.Number is set but can't after? BTW, properly enforcing this kind of restriction can be surprisingly difficult due concurrency considerations (just because your `SELECT COUNT(*)` returned 5, does not mean the actual number of rows will be 5 by the time you commit the transaction). Can you provide more details about what is it that you're actually trying to achieve? Perhaps there is a better data model for your needs?

Comment: Sure. This is an educational database. I am trying to create a table that lets users select the number of months they expect students to be on a course (as well as other details) - that bit is easy. Then depending on that on the number entered into the months column I want the second table to show the corresponding number of rows with the columns Month, Number_starts, Number_leavers, Number_achievers and the final column is a calculated column Number_InLearning. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon what database you are using, this can be done using triggers.

Alternately, you could do this in the application layer.

Comment: sql express 2012 - I am a bit of a newbie so any examples would be great.